# push_back vector of pointers of pointers

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<BPatch_point *> *points;
points = functions[0]->findPoint(BPatch_entry);
if ((*points).size() == 0)
{
  cout << "Failed to get the points" << endl;
}
std::vector<ldframework::Point *> *new_points;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < points->size(); i++ )
{
  ldframework::Point *pt1 = new ldframework::PointImpl((*points[0]));
  new_points->push_back(pt1);
}
```

The PointImpl constructor is :

```
ldframework::PointImpl::PointImpl(const BPatch_point&* po)
{
    Bpatch_point *_bpoint=new BPatch_point(*po);     
}
```

WHile compiling im getting following error. Could you please help

```
>BfunctionImpl.cpp: In member function âvirtual const std::vector<ldframework::Point*, std::allocator<ldframework::Point*> >* ldframework::BfunctionImpl::find_Point(ldframework::locClass)â:
```

> BfunctionImpl.cpp:86: error: expected type-specifier
>   BfunctionImpl.cpp:86: error: cannot convert âint*â to âldframework::Point*â in initialization
>   BfunctionImpl.cpp:86: error: expected â,â or â;â

THe 86 line number code is

```
ldframework::Point *pt1 = new ldframework::PointImpl((*points[0]));
```

Comment: Always listen to the compiler.

Comment: EVen I want to listen to the compiler error.I am asking how to fix this compiler error.

Comment: The compiler says that error is in member function `BfunctionImpl::find_Point` where is this member function?

Comment: The above lines of code is from find_point function only

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `(*points[0])` part of line 86.

Since `points` is a pointer to a vector and the array subscript operator [] has a higher precedence than the unary indirection operator *, this is parsed as `*(*(points+0))`.

You might try to replace this by `(*points)[0]` or maybe even: `(*points)[i]`

Furthermore, `new_points` is a pointer to a vector, that has not been assigned to a pointer to a valid object before it is used.

Additionally, I see that you use a lot of pointers, which causes extra indirections, decrease of locality, and gives you the burden of cleaning-up things or causing memory leaks. Does `new_points` have to be a vector of pointers to `ldframework::Point`? You could use a vector of  `std::unique_ptr<ldframework::Point>` to avoid the clean-up burden, but you can also consider:

```
std::vector<ldframework::PointImpl> *new_points =
  new std::vector<ldframework::PointImpl>;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < points->size(); i++ )
{
  new_points->push_back( ldframework::PointImpl((*points)[i]) );
}
```

or even better:

```
std::vector<ldframework::PointImpl> new_points;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < points->size(); i++ )
{
  new_points.push_back( ldframework::PointImpl((*points)[i]) );
}
```